# JQuery está resgatando o texto de options junto com o texto do label

Tags: javascript, jquery

Enquanto trabalhava em algo tropecei na seguinte situação. Segue o código com o "problema":

```js
var oi = $("label").text();
$("div").html(oi);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Hello
  <select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  </select>
</label>

<div></div>
```

Eu queria puxar apenas o texto da label mas os textos dentro dos `options` estão vindo junto. Tem como contornar isto com JQuery ou Javascript puro?

PS. Eu sei que é possível 'linkar' um label com um elemento usando o 'for' mas queria evitar esta maneira, estou trabalhando em um form extenso e criar id's únicos apenas para os labels é bem exaustivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var oi = $("label").clone().children().remove().end().text();
$("div").html(oi);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Hello
  <select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  </select>
</label>

<div></div>
```